# Fixing multiple definition of function compilation error

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, centos7

I know there are lots of questions about this error, but I don't understand what to do even after reading all those questions.

I have a project with multiple files, every header file has include guards. I'm getting the error just in one file, even though I did everything the same in all of them. Most questions I have read with this issue also have linker error in the error message, but I don't.

Here's an example:

```
/tmp/ccS7R7EN.o: In function `printUsage':
/home/prog/proj2/user.c:18: multiple definition of `printUsage'
/tmp/ccL1RR7T.o:/home/prog/proj2/user.c:18: first defined here
```

I have the exact same error for every single function in user.c Here's the function definition in user.h

```
void printUsage(void);
```

And here is the function in user.c

```
void printUsage(void){
    printf("Utilização: ./WarmingUp [OPÇÕES]\n");
    printf("Opções:\n");
    printf("  Modo de funcionamento: (Escolher um e um só)\n");
    printf("    -g Modo gráfico. Permite visualizar o aumento da"
           "temperatura global no planeta\n");
    printf("    -t Modo textual. Permite calcular um conjunto de "
           "estatísticas sobre o aquecimento (ou arrefecimento) global\n");
    printf("  Ficheiros: (Tem de escolher ambos)\n");
    printf("    -f1 nome_do_ficheiro Indica o nome do ficheiro com as "
           "medidas por país\n");
    printf("    -f2 nome_do_ficheiro Indica o nome do ficheiro com as "
           "medidas por cidade\n");
}
```

user.c includes user.h right in the beginning

```
#include "user.h"
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using gcc, this is the output of gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)
```

I'm using centos 7 everything.

Comment: Are you including `user.c` in one of your files?

Comment: How are you calling gcc to compile this file and all the others you're using?

Comment: @tkausl that was it. Silly mistake.

Comment: Somebody please make an answer, to get this out of the list of unanswered questions.